# OpenIDConnect Session Management passing session_state from RP to OP

Tags: openid-connect

I am implementing OIDC Session management. According to the specification 'http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html#CreatingUpdatingSessions' I need to send ' client_id + " " + session_state' from RP iFrame to the OP iFrame. I should pass a json here as the session_id which indicates the login status of the OP. In my OP I'm maintaining a cookie to store the login status. But I can't access it in the RP iFrame as accessing cookies through different domains is impossible. So how can I pass the session_state from RP to OP? Can I pass the cookie from OP to RP as a post message? Please advice me on this.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RP received the `session_state` value from the OP at the time of logon. To the RP this is an opaque value (which may or not be a JSON object) that just needs to be passed back to the OP in the RP iframe.

The RP communicates the `session_state` to the OP by by sending it from the RP iframe to the OP iframe using postMessage.

Be aware the RP creates both the RP iframe and the OP iframe. It is just that the content in the OP iframe is served by the OP and thus may access/use/process the cookie value in a way that is specific to the OP and independent of the RP and the RP iframe.

Comment: Hi Hans Z. You seemed to know about openID session Management very well. I am in a big trouble of implementing this. If I post the full code and ask you the doubts can you please help me. Because I cant send mails to the openidconnect list too though I subscribed to it. If you can, please help me.

Comment: you could take a look at my implementation here: https://github.com/pingidentity/mod_auth_openidc/blob/master/src/mod_auth_openidc.c#L1795